# Scrape Facebook with session from Passport Facebook

Tags: puppeteer, passport-facebook

My website already authenticated user using passport-facebook. But I don't know how to use that access token and import it to puppeteer and start scraping on Facebook. Because puppeteer will open new page and asking for new authentication.

Comment: Think of it in this way: how does Facebook know if you're authenticated or not in this or that browser?

Comment: So can I ask more permission from user that allow me to scrape data from their profile?

Comment: How does your website authenticate a user? Where is auth token stored?